# How to write regex that captures unlimited number of groups?

Tags: regex, parsing, regex-group

I have a string with multiple words like `str1, str2, str3, ... strN`. Number of words may be any and isn't known at time of writing regex.

Is it possible to write regex that will match the whole string and capture groups, one word per group? That is the following groups will be captured:

> Group 1: str1
>   ...
>   Group N: strN

**Cause:** This string is a part of larger string. Other elements of large string can be captured using regex. I can parse large string using regex and capture string with multiple words to one group. Then I can split this group into other `str(s)`. I think that solution with one with regex for whole large string without split will be more elegant if it exists.

Comment: And why a regex? A form of `split` sounds much more appropriate here.

Comment: Java but if there is no solution for Java, please, provide it for another language.

Comment: As @Mat said, split must be used, see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Provided your input string is called `input`:

```
final String[] groups = input.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

The `groups` array will contain all matches.

Comment: Thank you, but I was looking for regex solution, see updated cause in question. Anyway, split solution seems to be more elegant than regex one even if it exists.

Comment: Using only one regex for this is a bad idea, it quickly becomes unreadable. Especially since you say you can capture x,y,z,t... in a group: just extract that group and split it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something very similar: write a regex with just 1 group, but then check all matches of that group. In java it would look like this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(\\w+)\\b(?:,\\s)*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("str1, str2, str3, ... strN");
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

The result is:

```
str1
str2
str3
...
strN
```

The pure regex is `\b(\w+)\b(?:,\s)*` , where `(?:` is a non-capturing group (not counted as a group).